# Is this an incorrect way of redirecting the output of a child spawned by fork and execvp?

Tags: c++, process, io, exec, fork

I am trying to do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool foo = false;
    //parse args, check if --foo is an arg, if so mark foo true

    if (foo)
    {
        //child behavior
        while (true) { std::cout << "child" << std::endl; sleep(1); }
    }
    else
    {
        //do some parent process stuff
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) //spawn child
        {
            char* newArgv[argc+1];
            for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) newArgv[i] = argv[i];
            newArgv[argc] = "--foo"; //make child run child code

            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << argv[0] << " >> foo.txt 2>&1"; //same binary but redir child output
            execvp(out.str().c_str(), newArgv);
        } 

        //more regular parent code
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, basically, binary spawns itself with a new argument to run in a different way, and the output is redirected (ideally). Unfortunately, while this does spawn two processes, I seem to lose the output of the child and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. The redirection operators are handled by the shell, and you are not executing a shell.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the *much* simpler:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    //do some parent process stuff      
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) //this is the child
    {
       //child behavior
        while (true) { std::cout << "child" << std::endl; sleep(1); }
    } else {
        //more regular parent code
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong is that fork without exec only forks one thread and some of the threads in the parent have certain static once initialization which cause issues. exec gets around all those issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set filedescriptor 1 to point to `foo.txt` before calling `execv`. The child process will then use `foo.txt` as standard output:

```
fd_t f = open("foo.txt", O_WRONLY);
if (f != 1)
  {
    close(1);
    dup2(f, 1);
    close(f);
  }
execv(...);
```

Any bugfixing in the code above is left as exercise for the reader. Bugfixing includes, but is not limited to, checking for errors returned from the function calls.

EDIT:

If you want standard error (fildescriptor 2) to go wherever standard output goes, you have to add this before `execv`:

```
close(2);
dup2(1, 2);
```